# How to get android internet connection status?

Tags: android

How to get android  internet connection status for HTC One app development?

I'm new to android develpment and i'm going to develop an application with internet. so I need to get the interent status. Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10617567/1659523 check this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way and [Read more](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/)

```
public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
    int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
    String status = null;
    if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
        status = "Wifi enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
        status = "Mobile data enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
        status = "Not connected to Internet";
    }
    return status;
}
```

Or another simple way to achieve the task

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
    if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
        if (ni.isConnected())
            haveConnectedWifi = true;
    if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
        if (ni.isConnected())
            haveConnectedMobile = true;
}
return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

And in your android manifest:

```
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code : This code will work in all android version..

```
public static boolean isInternetOn(Context context) 
    {
         boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
         boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

         ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
         for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) 
         {
             if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                 if (ni.isConnected())
                     haveConnectedWifi = true;
             if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                 if (ni.isConnected())
                     haveConnectedMobile = true;
         }
         return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }
```

It returns the true if internet is on and false when internet is not available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to get Connection status.

```
public abstract class NetworkUtils 
{
    public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) 
    {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

You need to define following permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Now you can call above method using following lines of code in any activity you want,

```
if (!NetworkUtils.isNetworkConnected(getApplicationContext())) 
{
    // msg to display.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context)
{
  return ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
}
```

or

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
  boolean outcome = false;

  if (context != null) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
      .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo[] networkInfos = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();

    for (NetworkInfo tempNetworkInfo : networkInfos) {


      /**
       * Can also check if the user is in roaming
       */
      if (tempNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
        outcome = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return outcome;
}
```

Don't forget to add to manifest file this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi make a class ConnectionDetector as follows

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionDetector {

    private Context _context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
        this._context = context;
    }

    public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null) 
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null) 
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
}
```

you can use this class in given following way

```
ConnectionDetector detector= new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

Boolean isInternetPresent = detector.isConnectingToInternet(); // true or false
```

with this boolean isInternetPresent  you can proceed further in development.

```
if (isInternetPresent) {
                    // Internet Connection is Present


                } else {
                    // Internet connection is not present

                }
```

in support of all this  need to add permission into your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```