# How to get network status in android?

Tags: android

[image]

Is there any why to get the signal status of wifi and phone's provider that is shown at the top bar? Tried to search it across Stackoverflow unsuccessfuly.

**Thank in advance.**

Comment: [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697765/how-to-get-android-internet-connection-status) to get the Android Internet Connection Status. [Here is documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring) by Android Developers on how to Determine and Monitor the Connectivity Status. **Try them out**.

Comment: Hello Yariv. Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the **WiFi strength**, you can create the following function:

```
public static int calculateSignalLevel (int Rssi, int numLevels){
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    int numOfLevels = 5;
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiInfo.getRssi(), numOfLevels);
}
```

If you want to get the status of the device and whether it is **connected to the internet**, you can use the following function:

```
public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
    int connected = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
    String wifiStatus = null;
    if (connected == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
        wifiStatus = "Wifi enabled";
    } else if (connected == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
        wifiStatus = "Mobile data enabled";
    } else if (connected == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
        wifiStatus = "Not connected to Internet";
    }
    return wifiStatus;
}
```

Finally, to get the name of the **phone's provider**, you can use the following function:

```
public static String carrierName(){
    TelephonyManager manager =(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
}
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: If this answer helped you Yariv, please mark it as accepted so that others who are facing similar problems may refer to it and get help as well.